# Qual a melhor forma de fazer download de arquivos e salvá-los em pastas diferentes dentro do assets android?

Tags: android

[image: Tree folder]

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer download de arquivos pdf e salvá-los em pastas diferentes dentro da pasta assets do Android?

Por exemplo, na pasta A vou ter 10 arquivos específicos, na pasta B 20 arquivos específicos, então preciso verificar primeiro se os arquivos existem nas respectivas pastas e  caso negativo fazer os downloads.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: provavelmente você não vai poder salvar dentro da pasta assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível salvar um arquivo dentro da pasta `assets` depois de já empacotado e gerado o APK, pois ela é somente para leitura. Veja aqui na documentação do Android as [opções existentes de armazenamento](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

No entanto, se você quer verificar se já existe um arquivo dentro do `assets` antes de fazer *download* para **uma outra pasta**, seria possível através do nome do arquivo. Por exemplo, veja este método abaixo no qual está a verificar se já existe um arquivo dentro do `assets` passando o contexto e um nome específico como parâmetro:

```
public static boolean existFileInAsset(Context context, String file) {
    try {
        InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open("file:///android_asset/" + file);
        stream.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Sendo assim, basta fazer a verificação desta forma abaixo:

```
if(existFileInAsset(context,"jonsnow.pdf")){
    // aqui exibe qualquer mensagem considerando que o arquivo existe
} else {
    // aqui você pode colocar algum código para fazer download do arquivo 
    // pois se entrou aqui, é porque não existe o arquivo salvo com este nome.
}
```

#### No [**Kotlin**](https://kotlinlang.org/) ficaria assim:

```
fun existFileInAsset(context: Context, file: String): Boolean {
    try {
        val stream = context.assets.open("file:///android_asset/" + file)
        stream.close()
        return true
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        return false
    }
}
```

Para usar esta função no Kotlin, segue a mesma logica do JAVA.

Comment: Para deixar um pouco mais "kotlinizado" seria uma boa utilizar `extension`, algo como: `fun Context.existFileInAsset(file: String)...`

Comment: Obrigado pelos esclarecimento.